# How to keep dependent dropdown select values after form submission using codeigniter3,jquery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

[image]I am implementing dependent dropdown. In that dependent dropdown I filled up data successfully, But After submitting the input values, the select boxes get empty. I have to show the user which option the user selected.

The scenario is like Country->State->City Dependent Drop-Down

Here is my code

```php
    <select id="location">
        <option value="">Select Location</option>
        <?php foreach($location as $row) { ?>
        <option selected value=<?php echo $row['locationId'];?>><?php echo $row['location'];?></option>
        <?php end foreach; ?>
    </select>
    
    <select id="stage">
        <option value="">Select Stage</option>
        <?php foreach($stage as $row) { ?>
        <option selected value=<?php echo $row['stageId'];?>><?php echo $row['stage'];?></option>
        <?php end foreach; ?>
    </select>
```

jQuery

```js
    $('#location').change(function(){
        var locationid = $('#location').val();
        $.ajax({
            url : my url,
            type : POST,
            data : {locationid : locationid, selected : selected} //By googling I added selected, but no use
            success : function(data){
                $('#stage').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

```
 $('#form').submit(function(){
     var locationid = $('#location').val();
     var stageid = $('#stage').val();
     var empid = $('#employee').val();
     $.ajax({
      url : myURL,
      type : POST,
      data : {locationid : locationid,stageid : stageid,empid: empid},
      success : function(data){
       window.location.replace('myURL')
    
    }
    });

})
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['location'] = $this->myModel->getLocation();
} 

public function getStage()
{
    $locationid = $this->input->post('location');
    $data['stage'] = $this->myModel->getStage($locationid);
    echo $this->myModel->getStage($locationid);
}
```

my Model:

```
public function getLocation()
{
    return $query = $MainDB->query(".....")->result();
}
public function getStage()
{
    return $query = $MainDB->query(".....")->result();

    $output = '<option value = "">Select Stage</option>';
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $output. ='<option value = "'.$row->stageno.'">'.$row->stagename.'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: finally what you want???

Comment: Based on select box selected values I have to display the data. After select the options from select box, submit the form, the selected values will disappear. I want that selected options even after form submit.

Comment: `show the user which option the user selected` at edit page?.

Comment: please show me `picture` of what you actually want?

Comment: Do you submit final data with ajax as well or page reload?

Comment: Yes I am submitting form data with ajax                                                                                                              $('#form').submit(function(){})

Comment: @Sowmya Gayam please explain me with picture.

Comment: How can I add the picture here

Comment: by edit your post.

Comment: I edited my Code here, and I added image also here.  In the above picture, after I submitted selected Input values it shows like this, But my requirement is  the select box can't be empty while displaying data, those should show the selected options along with data

Comment: Hi , Can anybody give solution as early as possible. I need this solution urgently. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Sowmya Gayam location , stage will be selected after submit button which you chose in these after submit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222532/discussion-between-sowmya-gayam-and-kumar).

Comment: Anyone can give solution for this issue, I need this one is very urgent.